# merging cells in the middle of a table

Tags: tables, cell

I am trying to design the following table. The cells in the third and fouth row are merged. I tried multicolumn makes more column but I could not manage to do it in way that it merges.

[image]

Comment: b & \multicolumn{2}{c}{your text} \\ should give you the desired merges column in row 3.

Comment: Thank you both. It works. @leandriis and Jose